# Mathematical Induction with Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Let $\gamma_i=(-1)^i\dbinom{2n+1}{i}$ and $a_{n}$ be fixed.

Observe that:
$$\begin{array}{lllll}
a_{n}&=a_{n}\\
a_{n-1}&=-\gamma_1 a_{n}\\
        &=\dbinom{2n+1}{1}a_{n}\\
a_{n-2}&=-\gamma_{1}a_{n-1}-\gamma_{2}a_{n}\\
        &=\dbinom{2n+1}{1}\dbinom{2n+1}{1}a_{n}-\dbinom{2n+1}{2}a_{n}\\
        &=\dbinom{2n+2}{2}a_{n}\\
a_{n-3}&=-\gamma_1a_{n-2}-\gamma_2a_{n-1}-\gamma_{3}a_{n}\\
        &=\dbinom{2n+1}{1}\dbinom{2n+2}{2}a_{n}-\dbinom{2n+1}{2}\dbinom{2n+1}{1}a_{n}+\dbinom{2n+1}{3}a_{n}\\
        &=\dbinom{2n+3}{3}a_{n}
\end{array}$$

My goal is to show that for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}_n$,
$$a_{n-k}=-\sum_{i=1}^k\gamma_i~a_{n-k-i}=\dbinom{2n+k}{k}a_n.$$

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much!

(This is actually a form of the entries of a particular matrix I am working on.)

Comment: What is $a_n$? Why does the pattern you're trying to show off hold?

Comment: $a_n$ is actually $2^{2n+1}$, but I guess, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have tried to solve until $k=7$.

Comment: When providing clarification that is essential, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.